# Using the Corda account-based model, can I ascertain whether a transaction signer matches an account persisted on the state?

Tags: corda

I am experimenting with Hash Time-Lock Contracts in Corda, using the Corda account-based model.  It seems to me that, to transact with an account, you must always obtain an Anonymous Party to serve as its public key, via subflow RequestKeyForAccount.  And it seems that you will always obtain a different key each time you RequestKeyForAccount, even for the same account.

Assuming the above statements are correct, I am finding it impossible to implement the contract, as the contract must be able to identify whether the public key invoking it belongs to the "locker" or the "lockee" party.  The Anonymous Party will always be different, and will never match either the "locker" or the "lockee," because it will be different every time I invoke RequestKeyForAccount.

I have also tried tackling the problem in a different way, by storing "locker" **account** and "lockee" **account** in my persisted state - but, the contract does not have access to the *account* that is invoking it.  It has access to the **signers** - which are AbstractParties.  The **account** invoking the transaction does not seem obtainable.

Bottom line, I cannot implement a contract that tries to ascertain whether the account invoking it matches a particular account stored within the associated state, due to the random anonymized values returned by RequestKeyForAccount; and due to the inaccessibility of account when all I can access are the signers of the transaction, i.e. AbstractParties.  I'd appreciate if somebody can tell me if I am off-base in any of my statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember that Accounts in Corda are only logical entities. They do not sign transactions and they do not invoke flows in the cordapp. It's their hosting node that does it on behalf of the accounts they own.

So, as also stated in [training.corda.net](https://training.corda.net/libraries/accounts-lib/#design), if you want to restrict access to certain states to a particular account, you have to manage it outside of Corda (for example, create a RPC user that is linked to an account at application level, with the needed restrictions):

> Data access restrictions, i.e. restricting users (i.e. Corda accounts) to interact only with states that they own, is the CorDapp developer's responsibility as implementing them is outside of Corda’s scope.

Comment: Thank you very much Alessandro.  This is the confirmation I was looking for.